# Use Integer List Key with Apex Crypto

Tags: apex, encryption, crypto

SO if i am given a private key as follow:

```
[242, 2, 56, 23, 15, 5, 12, 105, 19, 47, 116, 89, 25, 152, 200, 215]
```

and an initialization vector:

```
[194, 125, 123, 26, 93, 136, 191, 35, 20, 86, 167, 197, 12, 138, 135, 92, 233, 39, 121, 166, 8, 2, 103, 44, 239, 115, 50, 155, 200, 238, 33, 99]
```

How would I go about using Crypto.encrypt in Apex? The example I found all use Strings for the iV and use an auto generatedKey as shown below:

```
Blob exampleIv = Blob.valueOf('Example of IV123');
Blob key = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
Blob data = Blob.valueOf('Data to be encrypted');
Blob encrypted = Crypto.encrypt('AES128', key, exampleIv, data);
```

Do I just do this?

```
String encodedString = String.fromCharArray(ivKey);
```

Somehow something does not feel right here, my private key as 16 numbers and my iv has 32, these are provided from a third party so I HAVE to use keys like the one I posted (the two keys I posted I generated at random for obvious security purpose). I am just trying to understand how to make this work in Apex if at all possible

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Using the code below:

```
List<Integer> key = new List<Integer>{242, 2, 56, 23, 15, 5, 12, 105, 19, 47, 116, 89, 25, 152, 200, 215};
List<Integer> iv = new List<Integer>{194, 125, 123, 26, 93, 136, 191, 35, 20, 86, 167, 197, 12, 138, 135, 92, 233, 39, 121, 166, 8, 2, 103, 44, 239, 115, 50, 155, 200, 238, 33, 99};

String charkey = Base64.encode(key);
String chariV = Base64.encode(iv);
String password ='passwd9999';

Blob Blobkey =  EncodingUtil.base64Decode(charkey);
Blob BlobiV =  EncodingUtil.base64Decode(chariV);
Blob BlobPassword = Blob.valueOf(password);

Blob encrypted = Crypto.encrypt('AES128', Blobkey, BlobiV, BlobPassword);
String encryptedDataStr = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encrypted);
System.Debug(encryptedDataStr);
```

with this class:

```
public class Base64 {
    static String[] codes = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/='.split('');

    // Encodes integers 0-255 into base 64 string
    public static String encode(Integer[] source) {
        // Preallocate memory for speed
        String[] result = new String[(source.size()+2)/3];
        // Every three bytes input becomes four bytes output
        for(Integer index = 0, size = source.size()/3; index < size; index++) {
            // Combine three bytes in to one single integer
            Integer temp = (source[index]<<16|source[index+1]<<8)|source[index+2];
            // Extract four values from 0-63, and use the code from the base 64 index
            result[index]=codes[temp>>18]+(codes[(temp>>12)&63])+(codes[(temp>>6)&63])+codes[temp&63];
        }
        if(Math.mod(source.size(),3)==1) {
            // One byte left over, need two bytes padding
            Integer temp = (source[source.size()-1]<<16);
            result[result.size()-1] = codes[temp>>18]+(codes[(temp>>12)&63])+codes[64]+codes[64];
        } else if(Math.mod(source.size(),3)==2) {
            // Two bytes left over, need one byte padding
            Integer temp = (source[source.size()-2]<<16)|(source[source.size()-1]<<8);
            result[result.size()-1] = codes[temp>>18]+(codes[(temp>>12)&63])+(codes[(temp>>6)&63])+codes[64];
        }
        // Join into a single string
        return String.join(result, '');
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> System.InvalidParameterValueException: Invalid private key. Must be 16
>   bytes.

I wish I did not have to use an Integer Array but I do not have much choice in the matter!

Answer (score 1):

We do not use a String for encryption, we use a [Blob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_blob.htm). The easiest way to get where you're trying to go is to use [EncodingUtil](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm)'s base64Decode function to the the format you need:

```
Blob exampleIv = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('yourBase64EncodedIvHere');
Blob key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('yourBase64EncodedKeyHere');
```

As we discussed in your previous question, if you absolutely insist on using an Integer array, you can use the code I put in my [previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148350#148356) to convert it to a base64 string, but you'll still need to use this decode method to get to the correct Blob data values.

Comment: I did that but I get: System.InvalidParameterValueException: Invalid private key. Must be 16 bytes. And unfortunately I do not have a choice with the Integer array.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and I posted the code above but unfortunately it is not working!

Comment: @Tekill Why do you not have a choice? There's no practical difference between a base64-encoded string and an array of integers once it finally gets converted to binary data...

Comment: @Tekill By the way, I just realized what you're trying to do. The IV and Key must be the same size for AES. There's absolutely no way a 128 bit key with a 256 bit IV is going to work with AES. What encryption algorithm are they trying to have you use?

Comment: perhaps I am just being stubborn and would like to get a solution where I can just input the keys that are being given to me, I tried with the  Base64 string right of the bat but I keep getting the: "System.InvalidParameterValueException: Invalid private key. Must be 16 bytes."

Comment: "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (128)" in the java code, they seem to be taking the two keys as they are above... This whole thing is very confusing. [Link to the Crypto java class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html)

Comment: @Tekill That mode requires 128 bits for both the key and IV, as far as I can tell. I think someone's getting confused and giving you bad information.