# AES128: Apex Encryption to Java Decryption Checksum Generation

Tags: apex, controller, encryption, crypto, decrypt

I am trying to integrate payment gateway into salesforce site, i have used the AES128 Encryption and same is use for decryption but while decryption i have used java code where i got the decrypt value as below

Output value :- "1\u000e\u0018\u001a7y&6-u:^@&/$3d87caf26f3daa75fbbef54a3ca48480676c828950be0db54JN5"

Expected Value:-

"4697a3e0a09423933d87caf26f3daa75fbbef54a3ca48480676c828950be0db54JN5"

Apex code for encryption:-

```
public String encrypt() {
    String encryptedString = '';
    Blob exampleIv = Blob.valueOf('Example of IV123');
    Blob crypto128Key = Blob.valueOf('r2AAAh9Z8AXvdey9');
    Blob dataToBeEncryptedAsBlob = Blob.valueOf('4697a3e0a09423933d87caf26f3daa75fbbef54a3ca48480676c828950be0db54JN5');
    try {
        Blob returnCipher = Crypto.encrypt('AES128', crypto128Key, exampleIv, dataToBeEncryptedAsBlob);
        encryptedString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(returnCipher);
        Blob encryptedVal = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encryptedString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       System.debug('Error in encrypt -->'+e);
    }
    return encryptedString;
}
```

Java code for decryption: -

```
private final BASE64Encoder base64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
private final BASE64Decoder base64Decoder = new BASE64Decoder();

private final byte[] ivParamBytes = { 64, 64, 64, 64, 
   38, 38, 38, 38, 
   35, 35, 35, 35, 
   36, 36, 36, 36 };

public String decrypt(String toDecrypt, String key) throws Exception
  {
    String decryptedValue = "";

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING", "SunJCE");
    cipher.init(2, new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(ivParamBytes));
    decryptedValue = new String(cipher.doFinal(base64Decoder.decodeBuffer(toDecrypt)));
    return decryptedValue;
  }
```

Comment: FYI all, marked the other (older) post as a duplicate since David has posted a good answer to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several issues or potential issues here.

```
Blob exampleIv = Blob.valueOf('Example of IV123');
```

This is definitely wrong. In Java, you have hard-coded an initialization vector as a byte string:

```
private final byte[] ivParamBytes = { 64, 64, 64, 64, 
   38, 38, 38, 38, 
   35, 35, 35, 35, 
   36, 36, 36, 36 };
```

If you want the same results in Apex, you'll have to use the same initialization vector.

N.b. hard-coding a constant initialization vector is [a pretty bad idea security-wise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector). You generally *don't* want multiple encryptions of the same value to yield the same ciphertext - that makes the whole shebang vulnerable to lots of exciting attacks the mathematical details of which I am not qualified to explain. It's also not the right way to test interoperability of two cryptosystems or implementations - you should just be checking that each can decrypt values encrypted by the other.

In Apex, you'll probably want to store this initialization vector as a hexadecimal string and convert it to a binary blob with [`EncodingUtil.convertFromHex()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm). Then you can supply it to `encrypt()`.

You haven't supplied very much information about how you've tested this code, but I suspect what you're seeing in your output - some binary nonsense bytes, followed by the end of your real plaintext - reflects the problem with your IV. You're essentially corrupting the first block of your text.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318430/explanation-of-self-healing-property-of-cbc-cipher-block-chaining) on Stack Overflow for more about how Cipher Block Chaining mode reacts to data corruption, which is what you've accidentally introduced here.

### Other Issues

```
Blob crypto128Key = Blob.valueOf('r2AAAh9Z8AXvdey9');
Blob dataToBeEncryptedAsBlob = Blob.valueOf('4697a3e0a09423933d87caf26f3daa75fbbef54a3ca48480676c828950be0db54JN5');
```

This is likely to be wrong. `Blob.valueOf()` doesn't convert encoded data, like hex or Base64. It just creates a blob containing the literal string value.

It's not totally clear to me what these values are - the second one is mostly but not entirely hexadecimal - but if they're anything other than literal ASCII, `Blob.valueOf()` is not the right way to handle the data. `r2AAAh9Z8AXvdey9` is 16 ASCII bytes or 128 bits, but that's not a typical representation of a raw cryptographic key.

Basically, the problems here are mostly cryptography, not Apex. Crypto is **really easy** to get wrong, and you need to understand how it works in order to implement it correctly even at a basic level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I am able to solve the issue as my initialization vector does not match

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the issue as the initialization vector is different than i am using.

I used to match the vector in apex same as java by using the below method in the link 
[Integer Array to Base64 String](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/148356/66006)

Thanks.